# Access hash value by numerical key value in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have the following hash:

```
{"_invite_email"=>"N/A", "xLsBD4LTAA_0"=>"Strongly Disagree", "xLsBD4LTAA_1"=>"Disagree", "xLsBD4LTAA_2"=>"Neutral", "survey_url"=>"http://fluidsurveys.com/surveys/marketing/charlotte-test-survey/", "_referrer"=>"http://fluidsurveys.com/surveys/marketing/charlotte-test-survey/", "JgmcuQm9XG"=>"None", "KtAT6FnCr2"=>"7", "16KXF8q2yh"=>"test_3", "survey_name"=>"Charlotte Test Survey", "_created_at"=>"2014-01-22 15:29:47", "_completed"=>"1", "D1VVmPRdIX"=>"No", "_username"=>"marketing", "_updated_at"=>"2014-01-22 15:30:06.838809", "_weighted_score"=>"34.0", "webhook"=>"event", "_pagepath"=>"6", "_language"=>"en", "GKXQAtqZeF"=>"test_2", "_extra_info"=>"weighted_score", "_invite_name"=>"N/A", "smR1irNIZl"=>"Wesley Chapel", "_locale"=>"298", "_id"=>"39384911", "qa6ekIlFr9_1"=>"test_number", "qa6ekIlFr9_0"=>"test_name", "_key"=>"743cb089d8fdba18fd80cce1dba677ccd7d20def", "_ip_address"=>"66.135.11.22", "_completion_time"=>"00:00:19", "zqZaH7fml2"=>"test_1"}
```

I need to create a really ugly model that has attributes like so:

```
model.q1
model.q2
model.q3
etc...
```

The above hash is being posted back to me as params from a webhook. I need to build my model, storing each value in my hash in the above model attributes. This is the idea:

```
model.q1 = params[0]
model.q2 = params[1]
model.q3 = params[2]
```

What is the best way to write that so that I can access each individual key/value pair and store it on my model?

## EDIT

This is my goal, and I'm 100% open to suggestions for improvement here.

I am receiving the above params posted back to me from a webhook. The actual parameters are the contents of a survey response. I need these responses in real time as I will be making decisions mid day based on the response rate, or how many responses I get back. I also need to see the content of the responses, not just a count.

The issue I am having is that I'm receiving responses from about 50 surveys. All of the surveys are identical, but the post parameters include unique identifiers (as you can see above) for each question. I can not access those identifiers, and I have no way of knowing what they are (unless I go through all 50 surveys and write them down). So, since the surveys are identical in order/question types, I plan to just store the data in a table based on the chronological order of the parameters sent to me. This way every survey will map up to the appropriate columns, and I can run SQL queries on this to do my analytics.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This can probably be solved much more elegantly, but you need to tell us more about the actual task.

Comment: Sure, see my edit above. Feel free to make any suggestions.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't tell us enough. You have data in a hash. Show us your code attempt to break that down. Give us an idea how you want to store the data in a table using column names. Why can't you access the identifiers if you have a hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to have a hash of param keys and model attributes.

```
attr_map = {"_invite_email" => "q1", "xLsBD4LTAA_0" => "q1"}
```

Then you can do

```
attr_map.each {|k, v| model[v] = params[k] }
```